# Creating Swap memory without rooting

Tags: ram, swap

I want to set up swap memory for my Android phone.

- How to set up swap memory without rooting the device?
- Is there an app for doing so?

Comment: I know only 2 swapper apps, both need root. Search for `swapper` in play store.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to set up swap?

Comment: to increase memory for playing heavy new games like Modern combat zero hour.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app in the play store, the name is "Swap No Root", it is from the same creator of "Swapper". A 2GB of Swap already shows a big performance change.